# How to allow users and admins to upload files and view all uploaded files in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Users and administrator can upload file (any type of file) and there is a specific page where users can see uploads. Is there any module that can be used for this or any other idea?

Comment: I think you're looking for [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a file field to a content type.  Then use views to construct the page that displays the list of files.

Answer (score 1):

There are two notable modules which allow various users to manage files, [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce) and [elFinder file manager](http://drupal.org/project/elfinder).